# Attaching a snapshot of D drive containing database file in AWS EC2

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-administration

I have a question regarding attaching a database. A quick background on my setup:

- Production MSSQL DB Server (AWS EC2 instance)
- UAT MSSQL DB Server (AWS EC2 instance)
- Database files are saved on D:\ drive on both machine and the D:\ drive is an Elastic Block Storage device (like a physical drive)

I am trying to restore a copy of Production on UAT but, I don't want to do it using the typical way of taking a backup of PROD and then restoring it to UAT.

I am just wondering if there is a way to take a snapshot of D:\ drive and then attach it to the UAT server and then attach the PROD DB to it and rename it.

Any idea if this will work?

Thank you!

Moose

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly:

- Create a snapshot of the D: drive EBS volume
- Create a new EBS volume from the snapshot
- Attach the new volume to the UAT server

These operations can all be easily done via the Amazon EC2 management console.

However, it will then be up to you to configure your application to use the data on that drive. It's likely that there's some configuration information on your C: boot volume and it might not be happy with the drive suddenly appearing or being swapped.

You could also consider using Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS), which is a fully-managed database service. It can manage the whole database and make it easy to snapshot and restore the database.

Comment: thanks @John Rotenstein. I really appreciate the respond. I think that clarifies my question.